# Angular 8 component doesn't display after adding resolver and dynamic layout combined

Tags: angular

After adding a resolver, the component is not displayed. The problem occurs only when there is dynamic change of the layout.

The test case is as follows :

The html template of the main app component is responsible for displaying the correct ng-container according to the activated layout.
The desired layout is configured with a data property of the route.

The test case has only two routes, /login and /home

On the login page, the login component is displayed in the layout 1. When i click on the link to display the home component, it is displayed in the layout 2.

I added a resolver for the router home component.
The home component is never displayed.

Tests in success :
- A test case without simple resolver with dynamic templating is ok.
- A test case with simple resolver without dynamic templating is ok.
- A strange test case with resolver which return a simple Observable with no delays is ok (interesting to understand problem i think).
- The code executed in resolve is ok (no errors).

Test case in error :
With dynamic templating and resolve with a delay to simulate :
- i clicked on home link from login component
- the router event is called and the name of layout is changed with data param from home router.
- the layout 2 is displayed.
- the resolve is executed.
In the DOM , the login component has not been replaced by the home component. So the home component is never displayed (ngOnInit and constructor not called).

- similar test case typing url /home directly in the browser is ko too.

Code of test case is temporarily here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-raidlg

Modules & Components Hierarchy :

```html
AppModule->AppComponent
  LayoutModule->Layout1Component
              ->Layout2Component
  LoginModule->LoginComponent
  HomeModule->HomeComponent
```

app.component.html :

```html
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="layout">
  <app-layout2 *ngSwitchCase=2></app-layout2>  
  <app-layout1 *ngSwitchCase=1></app-layout1>  
</ng-container>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RoutesRecognized } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  layout: number = 1;

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.router.events.subscribe((data) => {
      if (data instanceof RoutesRecognized) {
        this.layout = data.state.root.firstChild.data.layout;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

login.component.html

```html
<div>
    <div>Login component</div>
    <div><a routerLink="/home">Home</a></div>
</div>
```

HomeResolver.ts

```
import { Resolve } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable(
    {
        providedIn : 'root'
    }
)
export class HomeResolver implements Resolve<Observable<String>> {
    resolve() {
        return  of("Test").pipe(delay(4000));
    }
}
```

home-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [{path : 'home', data : { layout : 2}, component : HomeComponent, resolve : {resultat : HomeResolver}}];
```

configuration : (angular 8.0.x)

```html
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
```

DOM after /login

```html
<my-app _nghost-fig-c0="" ng-version="8.0.0">
  <!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-switch": "1"
  }-->
  <!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "2"
  }-->
  <!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "1"
  }-->
  <app-layout1 _ngcontent-fig-c0="" _nghost-fig-c2="">
    <p _ngcontent-fig-c2="">Layout1 component</p>
    <router-outlet _ngcontent-fig-c2=""></router-outlet>
    <app-login _nghost-fig-c3="">
      <div _ngcontent-fig-c3="">
        <div _ngcontent-fig-c3="">Login component</div>
        <div _ngcontent-fig-c3=""><a _ngcontent-fig-c3="" routerlink="/home" ng-reflect-router-link="/home"
            href="/home">Home</a></div>
      </div>
    </app-login>
  </app-layout1>
</my-app>
```

DOM after home link clicked from login component (bug => layout2 added  but login component not replaced by home component).

```html
<my-app _nghost-aeg-c0="" ng-version="8.0.0">
  <!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-switch": "2"
  }-->
  <!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "2"
  }-->
  <app-layout2 _ngcontent-aeg-c0="" _nghost-aeg-c1="">
    <p _ngcontent-aeg-c1="">Layout2 component</p>
    <router-outlet _ngcontent-aeg-c1=""></router-outlet>
    <app-login _nghost-aeg-c3="">
      <div _ngcontent-aeg-c3="">
        <div _ngcontent-aeg-c3="">Login component</div>
        <div _ngcontent-aeg-c3=""><a _ngcontent-aeg-c3="" routerlink="/home" ng-reflect-router-link="/home"
            href="/home">Home</a></div>
      </div>
    </app-login>
  </app-layout2>
  <!--bindings={
    "ng-reflect-ng-switch-case": "1"
  }-->
</my-app>
```

Logs from console

```html
12:05:15.603 app.component.ts:18 AppComponent -> constructor
12:05:15.619 app.component.ts:23 AppComponent -> ngOnInit
12:05:15.621 layout1.component.ts:15 Layout1Component -> constructor
12:05:15.623 layout1.component.ts:19 Layout1Component -> ngOnInit
12:05:15.628 console.ts:15 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
12:05:15.633 app.component.ts:26 Router event -> set layout : 1
12:05:15.639 login.component.ts:15 LoginComponent -> constructor
12:05:15.643 login.component.ts:19 LoginComponent -> ngOnInit
12:05:16.837 login.component.ts:22 LoginComponent -> onClick
12:05:16.838 app.component.ts:26 Router event -> set layout : 2
12:05:16.840 home.resolver.ts:17 HomeResolver -> resolve
12:05:16.844 layout2.component.ts:15 Layout2Component -> constructor
12:05:16.846 layout2.component.ts:19 Layout2Component -> ngOnInit
12:05:16.847 login.component.ts:15 LoginComponent -> constructor
12:05:16.847 login.component.ts:19 LoginComponent -> ngOnInit
```

The resolve method takes 4 seconds and Home component should be called after 4 seconds. In logs, we can see layout 2 is immediatly updated but with login component and not with home component after 4 seconds.
I think the DOM shouldn't be updated while resolve is not finished.

Which error I could do to get this behavior ?

Comment: I’m your components subscribe. Do a console log on layout. Maybe it’s not 1 or 2?

Comment: @JensAlenius Logs from console paragraph added.

Comment: try without the layouts. Just static divs.  <div *ngSwitchCase=2>Hello</div>  
  <div *ngSwitchCase=1>World</div>

Comment: @JensAlenius tried  <div *ngSwitchCase=2><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>  
  <div *ngSwitchCase=1><router-outlet></router-outlet></div> , same problem.

Comment: Perfect then its not your layout. Its the switch statement that’s not correct. Just remove it and use <app-layout2 *ngIf=”layout==2”><...>. You can remove the Ng-container

Answer (score 0):

It something wrong with the switchcase.

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="layout">
  <app-layout2 *ngSwitchCase=2></app-layout2>  
  <app-layout1 *ngSwitchCase=1></app-layout1>  
</ng-container>
```

Try

```
<ng-container [ngSwitch]="layout">
  <app-layout2 *ngSwitchCase="2"></app-layout2>  
  <app-layout1 *ngSwitchCase="1"></app-layout1>  
</ng-container>
```

Or just go for a *ngIf if no more switchCase will be added:

```
  <app-layout2 *ngIf="layout==2"></app-layout2>  
  <app-layout1 *ngIf="layout==1"></app-layout1>
```

Comment: I tried <app-layout2 *ngIf="layout==2"></app-layout2><app-layout1 *ngIf="layout==1"></app-layout1>, and same problem. I tried <app-layout1 *ngIf="layout==1"></app-layout1>  
  <app-layout2 *ngIf="layout==2"></app-layout2> and test  is ok (surprise). Same result with  ngswitch, i must test 1 before 2, very very strange. And if i remove resolver, so ngIf or ngswitch are ok with tests in any order.